# Setting cache header via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, caching, cdn, cloudflare

I'm setting a cache instruction via htaccess. Code:

```
#team pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(inc|out\.|admin) [NC]
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604801, public"
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)(/([a-z_]+))?/?$ team.php?team=$1&res_type=$3 [QSA]
```

I tested this at www.web-sniffer.net and the header output is curious:

[image]

**Question:** Why do I apparently have two readings for `cache-control`? Which prevails? The bottom one is the one that's intended. And should I also be setting for Pragma cache?

Comment: Why do you have `Header set` after `RewriteCond`?

Comment: Because the header should be output only if that condition is met. No?

Comment: No that's not the way to make it work.

Comment: You wouldn't care to... elaborate, and help? :) It seemed sensible; that, after all, is how rewrite rules are set.

Comment: I do care but it is difficult to write all that code in comments, that's why an answer below.

Comment: Aha, apologies - I should have guessed you were writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set header conditionally:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(inc|out\.|admin) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)(/([a-z_]+))?/?$ index.php?team=$1&res_type=$3 [L,QSA,E=cc:1]

Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604801, public" env=REDIRECT_cc
```

**PS:** We need to use `REDIRECT_` prefix before env variable `cc` because `mod_rewrite` adds this prefix for each env variable at the end of each rewrite loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks, but what's the significance here - merely that the header comes AFTER the rule? And this doesn't explain why I still see two `cache-control` headers coming through on websniffer.com

Comment: `Header` directive is not from `mod_rewrite` module hence you will have to use `env` variables as shown. Not sure about multiple entries but I thin only last one is used.